# Pause in TTS android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm developing an app which would read out the text in the document and I want to add a pause and resume functionality but I can't find any pause() method in TTS. Is there any way that I can pause..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to pause. Just call `TextToSpeech.playSilence()` see the code below from [here](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/app/src/root/gast/playground/speech/tts/TextToSpeechDemo.java).

It speaks some actual text along with some silence.

```
private void playScript()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "started script");
// setup

// id to send back when saying the last phrase
// so the app can re-enable the "speak" button
HashMap<String, String> lastSpokenWord = new HashMap<String, String>();
lastSpokenWord.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,
        LAST_SPOKEN);

// add earcon
final String EARCON_NAME = "[tone]";
tts.addEarcon(EARCON_NAME, "root.gast.playground", R.raw.tone);

// add prerecorded speech
final String CLOSING = "[Thank you]";
tts.addSpeech(CLOSING, "root.gast.playground",
        R.raw.enjoytestapplication);

// pass in null to most of these because we do not want a callback to
// onDone
tts.playEarcon(EARCON_NAME, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
tts.playSilence(1000, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
tts.speak("Attention readers: Use the try button to experiment with"
        + " Text to Speech. Use the diagnostics button to see "
        + "detailed Text to Speech engine information.",
        TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
tts.playSilence(500, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
tts.speak(CLOSING, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, lastSpokenWord);
```

}

Answer (score 3):

the TextToSpeech class has the ability to add a [setOnUtteranceCompletedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) (or for api level 15+ [setOnUtteranceProgressListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html))  which will let you attach a listener for when the TTS utterence is completed and then you can start your second utterence, or your pause, or whatever you need..