# Android text to speech

Tags: android

i am using android text to speech using TextToSpeech.OnInitListner.

My Samsung s3 has samsung text to speech and google text to speech engine.My problem is that i am not able to give pauses during sppech.Can anyone help me for that?

Comment: This has been asked numerous times.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970204/how-to-pause-android-speech-tts-texttospeech & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069725/pause-in-tts-android

Comment: here is a blog post on Android text to speech, "Android allows you convert your text into voice. Not only you can convert it but it also allows you to speak text in variety of different languages."                   http://a-droidtech.blogspot.in/2015/06/android-text-to-speech-tutorial-android.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for pausing, while doing a speech-to-text.